# S is a set of adherent values of a sequence $x_n$

Tags: limits, supremum-and-infimum, limsup-and-liminf

Let a sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a bounded sequence of real numbers. Define $\mathbf S$ as the adherent set of the sequence. Prove that $\lim \inf\;(x_n)=\inf(S)$.

An adherent set $\mathbf S$ is a set that consists of the limiting points of subsequences of $x_n$.

I have made several attempts but I do not how to proceed.

I believe the bounded property of $x_n$ in combination with the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem probably would be useful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: By adherent set, you mean set of limit points?

Comment: How do you define $\lim\inf$? I ask because I've seen it defined as the infimum of $S$.

Comment: @srm99 Adherent set is a set of values that consist of the limits of subsequences of $x_n$